# Make part of text in UITextView clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView` and inside of that should be 2 words that are clickable. I tried it with a NSMutableAttributedString` like this:

`TextView`:

```
let documentsTextView: UITextView = {
    let v = UITextView()
    v.isEditable = false
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    v.textAlignment = .center
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 13)
    v.textColor = .lightGray
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

`attributedText`:

```
documentsTextView.delegate = self

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Durch Klicken auf 'Registrieren' akzeptiere ich die Nutzungsbedingungen und die Datenschutzrichtlinien.")
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "Nutzungsbedingungen", range: NSRange(location: 52, length: 19))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "Datenschutzrichtlinien", range: NSRange(location: 80, length: 22))

    documentsTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

and my `shouldInteractWith` - method:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    if URL.absoluteString == "Nutzungsbedingungen" {
        print("nutzung")
    }else if URL.absoluteString == "Datenschutzrichtlinien" {
        print("daten")
    }

    return true
}
```

But at the moment Xcode throws this error message when clicking on any of the two String:

> Failed to open URL Datenschutzrichtlinien: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=252, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}

Another thing is that the texts `font`, `size`, etc. is not like I actually define it in my `documentsTextView`  but instead just standard font, size, etc. ...

I guess I have a misunderstanding on how `TextViews` work but can anyone maybe help me out here? Quite stuck here...

Comment: Obviously `Nutzungsbedingungen` or `Datenschutzrichtlinien` are not valid URLs

Comment: Secondly, if you're setting `attributedText` that means you don't use any formatting defined via `UITextField` properties - those apply if you set `text`. You need to provide formatting as attributes in your `attributedString`

Comment: so what is a valid URL? I was watching a youtube tutorial where he simply used "1" and "2" so figured you just need simple strings?

Comment: and how do I provide formatting correctly? I cant call `attributedString.font` for example